# Drag-and-drop and touch events not available in Chrome with a touchscreen on a Windows PC

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, touch, touchscreen

The following code logs all keyboard, mouse, touch events.

On a Windows PC (tested: both Win10 + Win7), with a touchscreen (Samsung), I noticed that:

- drag-and-drop works on the Desktop (Windows Explorer: you can select files) with a touch tap + drag
- **drag-and-drop doesn't work in Chrome**:

  - doing a touch tap + drag doesn't trigger any event (not even a `mousedown`)
  - no `touchstart`, `touchend`, etc. are triggered

I already tried `chrome.exe --touch-events` without success, and the same for setting `chrome://flags/#top-chrome-touch-ui` to enable.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var logEvent = e => { a.innerHTML = e.type + " " + (e.key ?? "") + " " + (e.code ?? "") + " " + (e.keyCode ?? "") + "<br>" + a.innerHTML; };
window.onkeydown = logEvent;
window.onkeyup = logEvent;
window.onkeypress = logEvent;
window.onmousedown = logEvent;
window.onmouseup = logEvent;
window.onmousemove = logEvent;
window.onclick = logEvent;
window.ondblclick = logEvent;
window.ontouchstart = logEvent;
window.ontouchend = logEvent;
window.ontouchmove = logEvent;
window.onpointerdown = logEvent;
window.onpointerup = logEvent;
window.onpointermove = logEvent;
```

```html
<div id="a">
</div>
```